# PostgreSQL: Search by json property in JSONB column that is populated as json array

Tags: sql, postgresql, jsonb

So I have this:

```
CREATE EXTENSION "uuid-ossp"; -- not related, just for the uuid_generate_v4

CREATE TABLE events (
  id UUID PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL DEFAULT uuid_generate_v4(),
  speakers JSONB NOT NULL DEFAULT '[]'::jsonb
);

INSERT INTO events (id, speakers) values (uuid_generate_v4(), '[
  {
    "id": "de3ae2c7-19f6-4c69-81ae-467034c06101",
    "email": ""
  },
  {
    "id": "c8cf8fe8-a6b7-4cbc-b2c7-729c6108ff5f",
    "email": "hello@example.com"
  }
]'::JSONB)
```

I need to get the **list of `event.id` where 'hello@example.com' appears in the "email" field at least once in the speakers JSONB column**.

I tried:

```
select id from events where events.speakers->'email' ? '"hello@example.com"';
<no results>
```

And many other snippets that never worked. I don't think this is such an unusual usage pattern!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to expand the array first with `jsonb_array_elements`

```
SELECT * FROM (
   select id, jsonb_array_elements(speakers) as event from events
) as a where event->'email' ? 'hello@example.com'
```